# Angular 4 set the focus in the dynamic generated textbox using viewChildran

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, viewchild

I have the dynamically generated textbox as below.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data; let in=index">
    <td>
                        <input #unitNumber type="text" name="workPerformed-workcode-{{in}}" [(ngModel)] = "item.unitnumber" >
                      </td>
<td> <!-- Search option is given to chose the unit number----></td>
</tr>
```

Here, the search option is given to choose the unit number, if it has been chosen, then the corresponding textbox will be focused on using viewChildran.

**My try is**

```
@ViewChildren('unitNumber') enteredUnitNumbers;

// for searching, I have used the material dialog box
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SearchEquipmentComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
      <!-- HERE I NEED TO DO THE FOCUS ON PARTICULAR TEXTBOX ---->
     // console.log(this.enteredUnitNumbers.toArray().map(x => x))
});
```

Above console.log shows undefined. My need is that once dialog box is closed the corresponding unit number textbox should be focused.

Kindly give solutions

Comment: What do you mean by "focus"? Your `console.log` is attempting to retrieve the value that was entered into the dialog's input, right?

Comment: No, set focus on the particular textbox. for testing, I have tried  Console.log Actually, that place only do the focus of the textbox should be happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
enteredUnitNumbers.toArray()[0].nativeElement.focus();
```

Replace `0` with the index of the desired input.