# Repeating the reference inside ngFor directive

Tags: angular

I came across to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898230/angular-4-set-the-focus-in-the-dynamic-generated-textbox-using-viewchildran), where this guy is repeating the reference of the input box as because used inside ngFor.

I just want to ask that is this okay to do something like this, I mean repeating the reference of the element and used inside the component like

```
@ViewChildren('example') example;

ngAfterViewInit() {
 // do something with example
}
```

Or one should go for the index number like `*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"`

Sorry if it's a dumb question and thanks in advance...

Comment: Not a very fitting question for SO, but yes, I believe it's fine to do this. [The doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variable-warning-notes) states "Do not define the same variable name more than once in the same template" but I'm pretty sure it means in the actual template, not in the rendered result of it. When using `ngFor` you only write `#name` once.

Comment: Thanks for the response and for the reference too...

Comment: You must use @ViewChildren('example') example:QueryList<any> see https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#viewchildren. Be carefull, sometimes you need subscribe to "changes" of the QueryList